# How to release app for testing on Huawei App Gallery

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, huawei-push-notification, huawei-account

In the Huawei Store, we could publish an app upgrade via **"Version/Upgrade"** menu. But once we publish it will directly appear in the store.

Is there any way to publish an app on the Huawei developer console for testing like Beta/Alpha texting in the Google Play console?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. AppGallery Console provides Open testing feature for developers to publish their APK to selected users before releasing it for all. The Opening Testing service is still in beta state. To launch an open test, you should send an email for the application. You can follow the [this official link](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agc-betatest-apply) to apply for an Open Test.

Answer (score 1):

You can try HMS Cloud Testing which provides a complete set of automatic test processes based on real mobile phone use. It tests automatically the **compatibility**, **stability**, **performance**, and **power consumption** of Android apps, without manual intervention.

Please refer the following articles for details.

[A Novice Journey towards Cloud Testing - Part I](https://forums.developer.huawei.com/forumPortal/en/topic/0203405524867740143?fid=0101188387844930001)

[A Novice Journey towards Cloud Testing - Part II](https://forums.developer.huawei.com/forumPortal/en/topic/0204412540054820222?fid=0101188387844930001)

[Cloud Testing: - Variety of tests on your Android App](https://forums.developer.huawei.com/forumPortal/en/topic/0201271583209350068?fid=0101187876626530001)